# ssh issues with zeroconf client on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, zeroconf

I have an embedded device which when connected via usb, it gets a IP assigned. I should be able to telnet to this device using the assigned IP.  I can see this in the ifconfig of my ubuntu machine.

Problem:
When I try to telnet, it does not connect and waits endlessly.

Workaround:
Disconnect the usb interface on my ubuntu system and run command `$sudo dhclient enp0s20f0u9` manually.  This refreshes the usb interface IP (getting the same ip address reassigned) but this time I can successfully telnet to the device.

This I need to do every time I plug in the device using usb.  Very annoying.  Any idea how to fix this permanently?

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround solution is via updating the routing table.

The routing table at first was:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.16.8.1      0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s31f6
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.252 U     100    0        0 enp0s20f0u9
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 docker0
169.254.0.1     169.254.0.2     255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 enp0s20f0u9
172.16.8.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s31f6
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
```

As we see, there are two entries for the interface `enp0s20f0u9`.  Deleting the below route also solved the issue.

```
sudo route del -net 169.254.0.1 gw 169.254.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.255 dev enp0s20f0u9
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this problem exists after Ubuntu 14.04.  This [post](http://forums.crackberry.com/blackberry-10-os-f269/connect-bb10-ubuntu-14-10-a-1066807/) provides a solution but I am not keen on trying this if it will break something else.